# Undefined property within foreach unless print_r'd

Tags: php

I feel I must be missing something here. PHP displays: **"Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date"** when trying to display a property from an outer loop but if I print_r() the line before, then it prints the value with no error. Comment it out again, and the error comes back?

I suspect perhaps **$iteration['EventTime']->date** is getting confused with the date() function in PHP but am not sure how to overcome this via an escape. I cannot change the format of the object.

Object:

```php
array (size=6)
  'LINE' => string '2' (length=1)
  'EventTime' => 
    object(DateTime)[2]
      public 'date' => string '2019-09-11 01:25:10.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
  'Tag' => string 'PLC32.J.A.10.NOREAD' (length=19)
  'Area' => string 'Material\PLC32' (length=14)
  'Message' => string '32JA10 Consecutive No-read Fault' (length=32)
  'FAULT_STATE' => int 1
```

Loop:

```php
foreach ($sqlsrv_fetch_all as $index => $row) {
    if ($row['FAULT_STATE'] == 1) {
        foreach ($sqlsrv_fetch_all as $iteration) {
            if ($iteration['LINE'] < $row['LINE'] || $iteration['Tag'] != $row['Tag'] || $iteration['FAULT_STATE'] == 1) {
                continue;
            } else {
                //print_r($row);
                echo "row: ".$row['EventTime']->date;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should output "row: 2019-09-11 01:25:10.000000
";
But unless I call print_r() first, it errors and outputs nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in PHP (I'm yet to find its ID in the bugtracker) that has been fixed with PHP 7.4 - [see here](https://3v4l.org/jZGhQ).

`print_r` is one of a few ways to display internals of an object, including its private properties. Apparently, before PHP 7.4, calling `print_r` on an object caused its properties to become public (presumably using reflections, so that their contents could be displayed), but never turned back after that.

[The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) does not name `\DateTime::$date` as a public field. If you want to display date, use [`\DateTime::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method instead.

Comment: Thanks, for explaining that, thought I was going crazy!
Got the date to show with `echo "row: ".date_format($row['EventTime'], "d-m-Y");` so thank you!